# What is Visual Source Safe equivalent for iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am a newbie for iPhone Programming. I would like to know how can we manage working on the same code in team in iPhone SDK?

Any easy tutorials to implement this would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Same as in any other platform: version control.

Comment: There is built-in SVN support in Xcode 3, and Xcode 4 will bring Git support. Other than that, you can manage version control from outside the IDE too.

Comment: @Nikita, Zneak: Thanks for your answers. Could you please guide to a good easy to understand tutorial to implement this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to 'implement' anything.
If you prefer git, [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info) has some references and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide) gives a lot of useful recipes.

For subversion, check [its tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/svn/info) and 'subversion book' link in there.

After that, just add your working directory to source control (excluding build dir and personal settings).

Those tools aren't iphone-specific, so you can use them in any project in any language in the same way.

PS **zneak** mentions xcode integration for svn, but I can't judge how useful it is.

**edit**
[Git community book](http://book.git-scm.com/) seems like a good starting point too. I'll add it to the tag wiki.